# SmoothPageIndicator(Expanding dot)

Tags: flutter, dart

I faced this problem that I need to change the size of the active dot. I resized the inactive dots, but I can't resize the active dots. How can I do this?

```
                     SmoothPageIndicator(
                        axisDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        controller: _controller, 
                        count: 3 ,
                      
                        effect: const ExpandingDotsEffect(
                          activeDotColor: Colors.orange,
                          dotColor: Colors.white,
                        
                          dotHeight: 16,
                          dotWidth: 35,
                          spacing: 24,
                          
                        
                           
                         ),
                        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `expansionFactor` property to do just that!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).